# PHP parse nexted XML with unique attributes

Tags: php, xml, parsing, recursion

I have a nested XML that I need to traverse and get not only the nodes, but also the attribute key and value which are each different.

I tried writing a recursive function in PHP to get what I was looking for. My XML looks like the following...

```
<document>
<character>
    <literal>name</literal>
    <codepoint>
        <cp_value cp_type="ucs">4e9c</cp_value>
        <cp_value cp_type="jis208">16-01</cp_value>
    </codepoint>
    <radical>
        <rad_value rad_type="classical">7</rad_value>
        <rad_value rad_type="nelson_c">1</rad_value>
    </radical>
            <meaning_group>
                <meaning>this</meaning>
                <meaning>that</meaning>
            </meaning_group>
     </character>
    ...
</document>
```

The problem is that not all [character] nodes have the exact same children.

I am trying to pull the attribute key and value to combine into one key, then associate the value as the value. If there is no attribute, I want to use the tag name as the key. Also, some children have the same name with no attribute. In this case, I want to just put them in one field separated by a line break. Thanks!!

```
["literal"] => "name",
["cp_type-ucs"] => "4e9c",
["cp_type-jis208"] => "16-01",
["rad_type-classical"] => "7",
["rad_type-nelson_c"] => "1",
["meaning"] => "this\nthat"
```

That's the array I want to output...

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

EDIT: Added some code that I can use to traverse through the layers and get the tag names to echo, but for some reason, they won't populate the array. Just the "character" tag will go in the array.

```
    function ripXML($file) {
    $xml = simplexml_load_file ( $file );
    return (peelTags ( $xml , array()) );
}
function peelTags($node, $tag) {
// find if there are children. (IF SO, there shouldn't be
$numChildren = @count ( $node->children () );

if ($numChildren != 0) {
    foreach ( $node->children () as $child ) {
        $tag [] = $child->getName ();
        peelTags ( $child, $tag);

        echo "<br />Name = " . $child->getName ();
    }
} 
    return $tag;
}

$file = "dictionarytest.xml";
print_r ( ripXML ( $file ) );
```

EDIT 2 - 
I figured it out finally. It might be a bit messy and not the best way to go about it, but it solved the problem that I was faced with. In case anyone else needed something similar, here it is!

```
$_SESSION ["a"] = array ();
$_SESSION ["c"] = 0;
function ripXML($file) {
$xml = simplexml_load_file ( $file );
return (peelTags ( $xml, array () ));
}
function peelTags($node, $tag) {
// find if there are children. (IF SO, there shouldn't be
$numChildren = @count ( $node->children () );

if ($numChildren != 0) {
    foreach ( $node->children () as $child ) {
        peelTags ( $child, $tag );
        $tag = $child->getName ();
        if ($tag == "literal") {
            $_SESSION ["c"] ++;
        }
        $value = trim($child->__toString ());
        if (isset ( $value ) && $value != "") {
            if ($child->attributes ()) {
                foreach ( $child->attributes () as $k => $v ) {
                    if (isset ( $v ) && $v != "") {
                        $_SESSION ["a"] [$_SESSION ["c"]] [$k . "_" . $v] = $value;
                    } 
                }
            } else {
                $_SESSION ["a"] [$_SESSION ["c"]] [$tag] = $value;
            }
        }
    }
}
return 1;
}

$file = "dictionarytest.xml";
print_r ( ripXML ( $file ) );
print_r ( $_SESSION ["a"] );
```

I used global session variables to store the array and counter for the recursive algorithm. I don't know if anyone has a better suggestion. I would like to optimize this function if possible. I was testing it on an XML file of only 5 entries, but my real file will have over 4000.

Comment: http://php.net/dom  learn that

Comment: Please show the code you have tried and why it isnt working.  What you want to do is possible.

Comment: do you need the attributes and values in a particular order?

Comment: I'm reading more on the DOM but still getting lost
As for my code, the original function I was using was able to pull the info, but I couldn't get the associations working at all so I scrapped it.
The values don't need to be in any particular order, just need to have the right key assigned to them...

Answer (score 1):

... confusing. i did not syntax check or test this, but i think its something like this..

```
$domd=new DOMDocument();
$domd->loadXML($xml);
$interestingdomnode=$domd->getElementsByTagName("character")->item(0);
$parsed_info=array();
$parsed_info['literal']=$interestingdomnode->getElementsByTagName("literal")->item(0)->textContent;
foreach($interestingdomnode->getElementsByTagName("cp_value") as $cp){
$parsed_info["cp_type-".$cp->cp_type]=$cp->textContent
}
foreach($interestingdomnode->getElementsByTagName("rad_type") as $cp){
$parsed_info["rad_type-".$cp->rad_type]=$cp->textContent
}
$parsed_info['meaning']='';
foreach($interestingdomnode->getElementsByTagName("meaning") as $cp){
$parsed_info['meaning'].=$cp->textContent.PHP_EOL;
}
var_dump($parsed_info);
```

Comment: Something along those lines would work, but unfortunately I'm dealing with nodes that might have more or fewer fields, different names, etc. so I didn't want to hard code the structure. I wanted something more abstract and flexible.

Comment: oh..sorry, i am too tired to figure it out, but i guess you have to loop $domnode->attributes

Comment: I got it figured out now! Thanks for the inspiration though!